# removeObjectAtIndex: is removing data from the main array and duplicate array as well

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

I have below code...

```
NSMutableArray *tArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
tArray = mainArray;
[tArray removeObjectAtIndex:mainArray.count-1];
```

In mainArray I have 4 items.

When I run above code what I was expecting is as below.

```
mainArray >> 4 items
tArray    >> 3 items
```

However I am getting result as below.

```
mainArray >> 3 items (this is WRONG)
tArray    >> 3 items
```

Any idea why the object is getting removed from main array when I do the removal from main array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tArray and mainArray are pointers. And they refer to the same array in your case. You should use

```
NSMutableArray *tArray = [mainArray mutableCopy];
```

to really copy array.

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

is not necessary since result will be discarded.

Comment: Perhaps add that the first alloc/init is completely unnecessary, and the result discarded. - Also you have to use `mutableCopy`, otherwise `tArray` will be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
tArray = mainArray;
```

set the tArray to be exactly the same array as mainArray, they point to the same object in memory so when you make changes to one of them the object in memory will be changed and all instances which points to it will see that change.

You should copy the array if you want to have two separate object.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
tArray = mainArray;
```

copies the reference of `mainArray` to `tArray` that is why the data is removed from both the array `tArray` and `mainArray`.

Try

```
tArray = [[NSmutableArray alloc] initWithArray:mainArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be explained like this:

1. `NSMutableArray *tArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
   implies a new object is created.
   tArray -> [a new object]
2. `tArray = mainArray;`
   implies both mainArray and tArray now refers to same object
   tArray -> [main array object] <- mainArray

and no one refers to [a new object], that is a memory leak in case of non-ARC as well.

Comment: It would be a memory leak only if you (still) use manual reference counting and not ARC.

Comment: yeah ofcourse, I wrote about memory leak only to get better understanding on how memory s allocated here. Editing, thanks.